# Number of ways to put $k$ dist balls in $F$ dist boxes where exactly $r$ boxes contain exactly one ball.

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

I need number of ways to place $k$ balls in $F$ boxes where exactly $r$ boxes contain exactly one ball. It means that exactly $r$ boxes should contain exactly one ball and another $F - r$ boxes should contain either $0$ or at least 2 balls $(0,2,3,4,5...)$.

In addition, I should say that balls are ***distinguishable*** and boxes are ***distinguishable***.

Actually, that's all.

Well, I can tell you my solution.

Let's consider that $N(r,k,F)$ - the answer to my question. i.e. number of ways to place $k$ balls in $F$ boxes where exactly $r$ boxes contain exactly one ball.

Well, let's compute it. Firstly, I can choose with $\binom k r$ ways my favourite balls (which I want to be lonely) and $\binom F r$ my favourite boxes (which I want to contain my lonely balls) and I can make with $r!$ ways concordance between $r$ balls and $r$ boxes. According to a combinatoric rules all of it give $\binom k r \cdot \binom F r \cdot r!$ ways of doing it.

After this, what should I do now? Now I have $F-r$ boxes and $k-r$ balls. And I should place them under condition that ***ZERO*** boxes contain exactly one ball. See similarity? It is exactly $N(0, k-r, F-r)$. Hm, Well, now I have equation:

$$
N(r,k,F) =\binom k r \cdot \binom F r \cdot r! \cdot N(0, k-r, F-r)
$$

of course $r$ should be $r\le\min(k,F)$ here.

Now I have some recursion. Well, let's think of initial conditions.

$$N(0,0,F) = 1$$

$$N(0,k,0) = 0$$

It is not enough. If I did not have this strange condition about favourite balls I would have $ F^k $ ways to place $k$ balls into $F$ boxes according to a famous basic combinatoric task. However, It means that the whole sum equals

$$
\sum_{s=0} ^{\min(k, F)} N(s,k,F) = F^k
$$

Consequently, let's think of $N(0, k, F)$ here.
$$
N(0,k,F) = F^k - \sum_{s=1} ^{\min(k, K)} N(s,k,F)
$$

NOW I have again 4 equations with some difficult recursion. I really do not like them. I can't do anything with these formulas. I want some help to simplify this or another solution. By the way, now my Python code does solve it. But I want to  get some beautiful solution to this problem.

PS I have already asked similar question and get a perfect answer for the case of ***indistinguishable*** balls.

[Number of ways to place $k$ balls in $F$ boxes where exactly $r$ boxes contain exactly one ball.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162269/number-of-ways-to-place-k-balls-in-f-boxes-where-exactly-r-boxes-contain-e)

But now I am trying to get solution for this case of ***distinguishable*** balls. I do not get how I should change solution of Markus with generating functions.

Comment: @hardmath why? I don't see any problem here

Comment: @hardmath actually I make my code work and there is no problem with even numbers, and for simple calculus, everything coincides. 

no-no-no, ***at least*** 2 balls. It can contain 3,4,5,...

Comment: @hardmath first of all, I have $F$ boxes. So, remaining $F-r$ boxes... 

I don't get what is redundant... But you are right. $r$ boxes have exactly one ball. $F-r$ boxes - not one ball.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your Question better now.

Comment: This counting problem can be framed as finding the number of *singleton-free* partitions having a specific number of parts.  The number of partitions of a set of size $n$ with $k$ parts is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), $S(n,k)$.  Authors seem to use a variety of notations for the number of singleton-free partitions (of a set of size $n$), but see Knuth, AoCP vol. 4A (Combinatorial Algorithms), page 436 where he introduces $\overline{\omega}_n'$ for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here  is  an approach based upon *[generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_functions)*.

> At first we  focus on the $r$ out of $k$ distinguishable balls which have to be placed in $r$ out of $F$ distinguishable boxes, each box containing precisely one ball.
>
> - Since balls are *distinguishable* we have $\binom{k}{r}$ different choices to select $r$ balls out of $k$.
> - Since  precisely $r$ boxes shall contain one ball we have
>     $\binom{F}{r}
>   $ different choices to select $r$ boxes out of $F$.
> - The selection of $r$ distinguishable balls can be placed in  $r!$  different  ways in the  $r$ selected boxes.
>
> We therefore get a total of
>    \begin{align*}
>  \binom{k}{r}\binom{F}{r}r!
>  \end{align*}
>    different configurations to place the $r$ balls into the boxes.

Next we focus on the remaining $F-r$ boxes which shall contain zero or more than one ball. We use generating functions to encode the configurations and since we have distinguishable objects we take *[exponential generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function)*. We encode the number of balls in one of these $F-r$ boxes as exponent and we consider
\begin{align*}
1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots=e^x-x\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Note that $\frac{x^1}{1!}$ is explicitely excluded guaranteeing that a box will not contain precisely $1$ ball. As we don't know *how many* balls can be placed in a box, we do not restrict the number of balls per box, indicated by $+\cdots$ in the series. We use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series.

> We want to place exactly $k-r$ balls in $F-r$ boxes. So, we are looking for
>   \begin{align*}
> (k-r)![x^{k-r}]\left(e^{x}-x\right)^{F-r}
> \end{align*}
>
> We finally conclude the wanted number of placing $k$ distinguishable balls into $F$ distinguishable boxes, so that precisely $r$ boxes contain $1$ ball is
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{k}{r}&\binom{F}{r}r!(k-r)![x^{k-r}]\left(e^{x}-x\right)^{F-r}\\
> &=k!\binom{F}{r}[x^{k-r}]\left(e^{x}-x\right)^{F-r}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

With some effort we can expand the expression (2) and represent the wanted number as expression with multiple sums.

> **Example:** Let's look at a simple example to better see what's going on. We take
>   \begin{align*}
> F=4,k=6,r=2
> \end{align*}
>
> We expand the generating function (2) with the help of Wolfram Alpha and obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> 6!\binom{4}{2}&[x^4]\left(e^x-x\right)^{2}\\
> &=6!\cdot6\cdot[x^4](1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+2\frac{x^3}{3!}+\color{blue}{8}\frac{x^4}{4!}+11\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots)\\
> &=6!\cdot 6\cdot \frac{\color{blue}{8}}{4!}\\
> &=1440
> \end{align*}

We encode the six balls with $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and place for illustration purpose the selection $\{1,2\}$ in two out of six boxes.

> We see there are $\binom{4}{2}2!=12$ different configurations.
>   \begin{array}{cccccccc}
> 1&2&.&.\qquad&\qquad2&1&.&.\\
> 1&.&2&.\qquad&\qquad2&.&1&.\\
> 1&.&.&2\qquad&\qquad2&.&.&1\\
> .&2&1&.\qquad&\qquad.&1&2&.\\
> .&2&.&1\qquad&\qquad.&1&.&2\\
> .&.&2&1\qquad&\qquad.&.&1&2\\
> \end{array}
>   and since there are $\binom{6}{2}=15$ valid configurations to select $2$ balls out of $6$, we have a total of $12\cdot 15=480$ configurations of the above kind.
>
> Each of them correspond to $8$ valid configurations  placing the remaining $4$ balls into $F-r=2$ boxes, resulting in a total of $480\cdot8=1440$ valid configurations. For example the first one expands to
>   \begin{array}{cccc}
> 1&2&\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{3,4,5,6}\\
> 1&2&\color{blue}{3,4}&\color{blue}{5,6}\\
> 1&2&\color{blue}{3,5}&\color{blue}{4,6}\\
> 1&2&\color{blue}{3,6}&\color{blue}{4,5}\\
> 1&2&\color{blue}{4,5}&\color{blue}{3,6}\\
> 1&2&\color{blue}{4,6}&\color{blue}{3,5}\\
> 1&2&\color{blue}{5,6}&\color{blue}{3,4}\\
> 1&2&\color{blue}{3,4,5,6}&\color{blue}{0}\\
> \end{array}

Comment: Wow, actually it is a lot easier, than I tried to do. Well, I need to read more about generating functions. Honestly, it is not clear for me how we naturally ***encode***. It sounds like: "Hey lets think that in denominator we will put this number of permutations and at the degree - amount of balls". But why exactly like this -- it is not clear. This idea has not occurred to me.

Well, I appreciate your indifferent to the problem, and actually I am sad that I did not think to this solution myself.

Thank you!

Comment: @Dida: You're welcome, thanks! :-) H. Wilf's *Generatingfunctionology* is the perfect starter. You might find *[this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742083/book-on-combinatorial-identities/748850#748850)* useful.

Answer (score 0):

The generating function for this is of the exponential variety and is

$$f(x)=\binom{F}{r}x^r(e^x-x)^{F-r}$$

This is the exponential generating function for selections of words length $k\ge r$ from a multiset of $r$ types of letters such that exactly 1 each of $r$ must be used and any non-negative amount *except* 1 of the remaining $F-r$ letters may be used.

We allow each letter type choose one of the locations (numbered balls) $1,2,\ldots,k$ to be in the box labelled with said letter type.

The desired count is therefore $\left[\frac{x^k}{k!}\right]f(x)$.

The function may be expanded as a binomial then the exponential as a Taylor series

$$\begin{eqnarray}f(x)&=&\binom{F}{r}x^r\sum_{j=0}^{F-r}(-1)^{F-r-j}\binom{F-r}{j}x^{F-r-j}e^{jx}\\
&=&\binom{F}{r}\sum_{j=0}^{F-r}x^{F-j}(-1)^{F-r-j}\binom{F-r}{j}\left(\sum_{l\ge 0}\frac{j^lx^l}{l!}\right)\\
&=&\binom{F}{r}\sum_{j=0}^{F-r}\sum_{l\ge 0}(-1)^{F-r-j}\binom{F-r}{j}\frac{j^l}{l!}x^{F+l-j}\\
&=&\binom{F}{r}\sum_{j=0}^{F-r}\sum_{k\ge F-j}(-1)^{F-r-j}\binom{F-r}{j}\frac{j^{k-F+j}}{(k-F+j)!}x^{k}\\
&=&\binom{F}{r}\sum_{k\ge r}\left(k!\sum_{j=\max(0,F-k)}^{F-r}(-1)^{F-r-j}\binom{F-r}{j}\frac{j^{k-F+j}}{(k-F+j)!}\right)\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\end{eqnarray}$$

the last step involves swapping the order of summation so that
$$\text{desired count}=\left[\frac{x^k}{k!}\right]f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\binom{F}{r}k!\sum_{j=\max(0,F-k)}^{F-r}(-1)^{F-r-j}\binom{F-r}{j}\frac{j^{k-F+j}}{(k-F+j)!}&,\, k\ge r\\
0&,\, \text{else}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I am sorry, but what for some negative cases?

For example, let's try $r = 1$, $k=4$, $F=6$. 

I can do this by $1|234|0|0|0|0|$ - at least, one way is here. 

But your formula claims that there is zero combinations. And you will be confused when you will see $(1-4+1)! = (-4)!$ in your formula. And you will be confused when you will get zero in negative power.

So, actually, you should make $k-F + j \ge 0$, isn't it? It will add some missing summands...

Comment: Yes, indeed.$k-F+j\ge 0$ . I will change the limit of the summation.

Comment: I think this takes care of the limits issue. Please comment if there is anything else.

Comment: how do you come to $k \ge 0$? Yes, else in this problem desired count will be zero. but you have $l\ge0$ and $l= k-F+j$. There is why I said about $k-F+j \ge 0$. But now I see $k\ge r$. How did $r$ appear there?

Comment: $k \ge r$, sorry

Comment: Actually, my computations. the same answer, however
$$\begin{multline}
\sum_{j=0}^{F-m}x^{F-j}(-1)^{F-m-j}\binom{F-m}{j}\left(\sum_{l=0}^{+\infty}\frac{j^l x^l}{l!}\right)=\\=\sum_{j=0}^{F-m}\sum_{l = 0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{F-m-j}\binom{F-m}{j}\frac{j^l}{l!}x^{F+l-j}=\\
=\sum_{j=0}^{F-m}\sum_{k = j-F}^{+\infty} (-1)^{F-m-j}\binom{F-m}{j}\frac{j^{k-F+j}}{(k-F+j)!}x^{k}=\\
=\sum_{k = 0 }^{\infty}\left(k!\sum_{j=\max(0,F-k)}^{F-m}(-1)^{F-m-j}\binom{F-m}{j}\frac{j^{k-F+j}}{(k-F+j)!}\right)\frac{x^{k}}{k!}
\end{multline}$$

Comment: I see what you mean, I put the lower limit on $k$ before changing the order of summation. I will edit that glitch, though the result remains. You appear to be using $m$ in place of $r$. We agree on the final formula though, good work!

Comment: Note that the minimum $k$ is for $j=F-r$ and $l=0$ since $k=F+l-j$, giving minimum $k=r$ not $k=0$. There are always at least as many balls $k$ as boxes with exactly 1 ball $r$.

Comment: Oh, I missed that, thank you!